# Separable differential equation $y'e^x=\frac 1 {\ln(y)}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Hello everyone I am stuck with this equation with an initial value, i have no idea what to do anymore with this i tried to integrate both terms and got blocked

The equation: 
$$y'e^x=\frac{1}{\ln(y)}$$

PS: forgot to add the inital value it is $y(0)=e$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$y'e^x=\frac{1}{\ln(y)}$$
It's separable
$$\int \ln(y)dy=\int e^{-x}dx$$
$$y\ln(y)-y=-e^{-x}+K$$
For $y(0)=e \implies K=1 $

Therefore
$$\boxed{y\ln(y)-y=1-e^{-x}}$$

Comment: Thanks thats where i got stuck i forgot to add the initial value that made me got stuck

Comment: yw @JorgeFilipe .....

Answer (score 2):

We have $$y' e^{x} = \frac{1}{\ln(y)}$$
Rewritting, we can represent this as
$$e^{-x} = y'\ln(y)$$
Integrating, we have 
\begin{align*}
\int e^{-x}dx &= \int y'\ln(y) dy\\
\Rightarrow -e^{-x} &= y\ln(y) - y + C
\end{align*}
Can you finish it from here?

Comment: I got that already just forgot to add the initial value that i'm supposed to use to calculate the C

Comment: Ok, so then plug in and solve for $C$. Then you are done.

Comment: Having a dumb moment but am i not supposed to have the y alone in one term to plug the value? (added the value on the top in an edit)

Comment: I believe the above answer from Isham satisfies your question :).

Comment: just saw it now thanks!

Comment: No problem, he beat me to it so wanted to give him the credit.